# Relation between one table records

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite, relationship

I have a User table.Some Users have a manager which is a user too.
I need `one to many` relationship between users, but I don't want to create a new table for that.

I can use `manager_id` to relate users to their manager.

**Now my question**

Is it a right way to do some thing like that? If no, so what's the best way?

---

*I'm using laravel and sqlite, relation is one to many*

Comment: Perhaps if you show the **code** you used to try to make it work in Laravel we could provide a suggestion as to why it was not working

Comment: My question is about concept (mostly)

Comment: Can a user have multiple managers? Then you need two tables. One user table with a flag, saying if the user is a manager or not. Then a user_manager table with the user id and the managers user id. There's no way around having that extra table if you want a sound architecture.

Comment: As I said, it's `one to many`, any user just has one manager. In the other word , its `many to one` many user has one manager

Comment: Then you have an answer below that should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the User table, you can add manager_id. This will create parent to child relationship. It will also support multiple hierarchies where managers can also have managers.

I have used this same model on categories which have sub categories.

This will work

Comment: Is it a good practice to use such relations ?

Comment: @MMD Many live systems couldn't have existed without it.